# How do I share a post for the ME3 missions?

Tags: support, me3missions

Okay, so I need to know how to share posts. I used the icons to share via Facebook but it didn't register! Do I have to wait a while? Please, I would like an answer. :D

Comment: 5 people need to click the link. Also, this is a question for meta.

Answer (score 4):

To share a post you need to either copy and share with your friends the link which appears when you click the "link" button under the question, or you can use the built-in mechanisms for publishing via Google+, Facebook and Twitter, by clicking the appropriate buttons on the left of the question.

For the purpose of the currently-running Mass Effect 3 promotion, you need 5 different people to actually click on the link you have shared, in order for it to count as a shared post. The post also needs to have at least one upvote.

You can see this information (and more) under the contest rules (click the "contest rules" button on http://me3missions.com/):

> For post sharing: use sharing buttons embedded in the question page on the left side or the permalink below the question. Shared posts should have a score greater than 1 and at least five click-throughs on the shared link.

Comment: It should be noted that you are in no way required to share *your own posts* for this promo. In fact, I found it easier in many cases to share other peoples posts that I found interesting or helpful!

Comment: Will sharing the same post to more than one place count as 1 share or 1 share for each place?

Comment: @Blem [We've assumed](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/mass-effect-3-missions-on-gaming-se) (see comments) that they don't check the referrer, so you need unique links (i.e., unique posts) for each share.

Comment: @Blem It's not about actual "posts," but about how many people click the link and come to the site.  That's how it actually tracks how many times you've dhared it.  I assume it tracks unique IP addresses, though, so you can't click on it 5 times yourself :)

Comment: @DaveMcClelland You're conflating "shares" with "views".  One share consists of 5 views (via your referral link) on 1 post.

Comment: @MatthewRead Ahh, good call. Thanks